# Drawing squares with Pygame; draw method only takes integers?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to draw some black squares on a white screen using Pygame. Here is my problem using the `pygame.draw.rect()` method:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (10, 10, 10, 10), 0) #no error
```

But I actually have lots of black square to plot so I want something like this:

```
a1 = (10, 10, 10, 10)
a2 = (20, 20, 10, 10)
A = [a1, a2]
for i in A:
   pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, A[i], 0) #gives error
```

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

But if I try this I don't get an error:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, a1, 0) #no error
```

Any ideas?

Comment: think about what `i` is. The problem is on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over the elements of the array (tuples) instead of the indexes of A. There are several ways to do what you want. Here are the first two I thought of:

```
for i,_ in enumerate(A):

for i in range(len(A)):
```